# How to populate a dropdown box with jQuery from a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object stored as a JavaScript string var containing both names and values for populating a dropdown box, say #dropdown. My question is, how can I access each element as value/label pairs and put them into a dropdown?

The json string looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Name1","value":"Val1"},{"name":"Name2","value":"Val2"}]
```

Does this need to be further parsed in any way?

I tried something like (but did not work)...

```
$(json).map(function () {
     return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.name);
  }).appendTo('#copy_input');
```

In what way do I need to further format my json to be able to easily iterate and fill the dropdown?

Comment: Your code works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/Fsf7g/. Are you sure there exists an element with id `copy_input`?

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I think the problem is with the id and not with the actual code here. One of those cases where the problem isn't where you think it is :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below and see if this works?

```
$(json).map(function () {
    var elem = $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.name)
    elem.appendTo('#copy_input');
    return 0; // dummy statement. You should be able to skip this statement too.
});
```

Comment: This does work, I had an unrelated issue with the id not being found somehow. Thanks!

Comment: How can I add attribute label also to the option.